# file name in the url

Tags: php

hello guys
i want to make my download system like

```
/download?file=815|file_name
```

and i already did that
but when it appear in the google search in appear like

```
download?file=815%7Cfile_name
```

do you think is that good idea to add the file name in the url as a just name no variable

Comment: could you define : "just name no variable"?

Comment: i mean the name i want it just text and i dont want to make it like &name=val

Answer (score 4):

using special chars in the URL is not a good idea. What you can do is forgetting the standard url and use something like this : /download/815/filename and then use the URL Rewrite engine of apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: I give you the possible rule : RewriteRule   ^/download/([^/]*)/(.*) /download?file=$1

Comment: i know how i can do, but i just asking about the url form

Comment: The answer is : do not use special char in your url. You can replace | by /. But still, using rewriting would be better

Answer (score 1):

Just use the file id download?file=8155555, I assume the path of the file is mapped to your db somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Its not secure, But you like to use this format of url, You should check that urls variables/inputs by php user input injection methods.

Thats will help to secure your website.

1 more.
 In SEO purpose, good to skip the special symbols in the urls.